# Excluding files from coverage when using Mocha and Istanbul

Tags: node.js, jenkins, mocha.js, istanbul

How can I exclude folders and files (by path) from coverage report when using mocha and instanbul?

I want to exclude by a configuration and not

```
/*istanbul ignore next*/
```

in each file.

(The generated report use by Jenkins)

Thanks,

Comment: How are you invoking Istanbul?

Comment: What do you mean by invoke?

Comment: How are you running Istanbul? I ask because there's a command line option to exclude files.

Comment: I run: `istanbul cover _mocha -- --recursive -R tap test/ > test.tap && istanbul report clover`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can ignore files matching a certain pattern using the `-x` parameter.

```
 istanbul help cover

 ...
 -x <exclude-pattern> [-x <exclude-pattern>]
        one or more fileset patterns e.g. "**/vendor/**"
 ...
```

Comment: How to do this in the Config Files, e.g. GruntFile?

Comment: Depends on what grunt library you use to wrap istanbul. In `grunt-karma` I'm excluding a folder (`app/tests`) like this: `{..., preprocessors['app/{*.js,!(tests)/**/*.js}'] = ['coverage'], ...}`

Answer (score 16):

If you run `istanbul help config` you'll see istanbul's default configuration. You can copy/paste the default config into a `.istanbul.yml` file at the root of your source tree, then store the exclusions in it.

Here's what mine looks like (this makes it easy to exclude many directories):

```
verbose: false
instrumentation:
    root: .
    extensions:
        - .js
    default-excludes: true
    excludes: ['**/tinymce/**', '**/lib/**', '**/tools/**', '**/build/**']
    embed-source: false
    variable: __coverage__
    compact: true
    preserve-comments: false
    complete-copy: false
    save-baseline: false
    baseline-file: ./coverage/coverage-baseline.json
    include-all-sources: true
    include-pid: false
    es-modules: false
reporting:
    print: summary
    reports:
        - lcov
    dir: ./tools/coverage
    watermarks:
        statements: [50, 80]
        lines: [50, 80]
        functions: [50, 80]
        branches: [50, 80]
    report-config:
        clover: {file: clover.xml}
        cobertura: {file: cobertura-coverage.xml}
        json: {file: coverage-final.json}
        json-summary: {file: coverage-summary.json}
        lcovonly: {file: lcov.info}
        teamcity: {file: null, blockName: Code Coverage Summary}
        text: {file: null, maxCols: 0}
        text-lcov: {file: lcov.info}
        text-summary: {file: null}
hooks:
    hook-run-in-context: false
    post-require-hook: null
    handle-sigint: false
check:
    global:
        statements: 0
        lines: 0
        branches: 0
        functions: 0
        excludes: []
    each:
        statements: 0
        lines: 0
        branches: 0
        functions: 0
        excludes: []
```

Comment: Are you sure excludes works with include-all-sources set to true?  

instrumentation:
  root: src
  include-all-sources: true
  verbose: true
  excludes: ["\*\*/src/client/\*\*"]
reporting:
  dir: "coverage"

And I'm still getting client files in my report.

Answer (score 5):

I your case I would use the following:

```
istanbul -x "**/pattern/to/exclude/**" cover _mocha -- --recursive -R tap test/ > test.tap && istanbul report clover –  snoof 9 hours ago
```

You can exclude multiple patterns just by adding multiple `-x` options.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the suggestions,

This was the solution:

```
istanbul cover -x '**/config/**'  _mocha -- --recursive -R tap test/ > test.tap && istanbul report clover
```