# Gitlab failed pipeline when merging yaml file

Tags: gitlab, swagger, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to merge a yaml file containing 7000 lines of swagger documentation into gitlab but the pipeline keeps failing. The failure is happening because there are no unit tests, but I'm not aware of a way to unit test a swagger file. I've included the script that's causing the failure. Thanks for all and any help.

script:
**"testForbidOnly": "npm run apolloEnv && TEST=true nyc mocha --recursive --exit --forbid-only"**

Comment: The error would be helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the code coverage tool Istanbul (cli: `nyc`) to ignore files with the `yml|yaml` extension. See: [Excluding files from coverage when using Mocha and Istanbul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327830/excluding-files-from-coverage-when-using-mocha-and-istanbul).